# Using Codeception functional tests to POST data

Tags: php, laravel, functional-testing, codeception

I want to create a test which will directly post data to a Laravel page to test it handling bad data.

I can run an acceptance test starting at the page with the form on, call `$I->click('Search');` and the page processes the data as expected.

Reading the introduction to Functional Tests on the Codeception website, it states

`In simple terms we set $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST variables, then we execute your script inside a test, we receive output, and then we test it.`

This sounds ideal, set an array of POST data and fire it directly at the processing page. But I can't find any documentation for it. I've played with `sendAjaxPostRequest` but it's not passing anything to $_POST.

Is there a way I can test the pages in isolation like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the solution lies with the [Codeception REST module](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST).

Adding this to the `functional.suite.yml` file allows you to write:

```
$I = new TestGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('check a page is resistant to POST injection');
$I->sendPOST(
    'search',
    array(
        'startDate' => '2013-07-03',
        'endDate' => '2013-07-10',
        'exec' => 'some dodgy commands',
    ));
$I->see('Search results');
$I->dontSee('Dodgy command executed');
```

A little clunky, but it allows testing of a single page.

Answer (score -3):

From the manual @ http://codeception.com/docs/04-AcceptanceTests

```
$I->submitForm('#update_form', array('user' => array(
     'name' => 'Miles',
     'email' => 'Davis',
     'gender' => 'm'
)));
```

Comment: That relies on the preceding page with the form. If I could do something like that but specify the target instead of relying on a form selector, then I could test it in isolation.

Comment: Hm, I got no solution for you. Maybe you should knock on some doors @codeception for this...